# Could not create a cross platform ARCore session (ErrorInvalidArgument). GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreIOSLifecycleManager:EnableSession()

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, arcore

I'm using Unity 2017.3.1F1 / Unity 2017.4.3f1 with ARCore Unity SDK 1.2.0/1.2.1 and Unity-AR-Kit Plugin dated 2018-5-9 along with the information provided at https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-ios and XCode 9.4 testing on a iPhone 6S Plus with iOS 11.3 installed.

Testing using the scene "HelloAR"

No matter what combination I do of Unity vs ARCore vs Unity-AR-Kit Plugin, I will always get in XCode:

> Could not create a cross platform ARCore session (ErrorInvalidArgument).
>
> GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreIOSLifecycleManager:EnableSession()
>
> (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
>
> Could not create a cross platform ARCore session (ErrorInvalidArgument).
>
> GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreIOSLifecycleManager:EnableSession()
>
> (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
>
> 2018-06-03 19:14:03.789899-0400 arkitscene[410:71922] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
>
> 2018-06-03 19:14:03.790091-0400 arkitscene[410:71922] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Looking for suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same exact errors. I'm finding that the actual demo app just says "Searching for surfaces.." but that the camera doesn't actually show anything. Also, the Camera Usage Notification doesn't even popup (I think this is the culprit)

Comment: I got an answer. Not all the example scenes work in iOS. Actually, just the AnchorCloud scene is the only one what works crossplatform.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you hear about this?

Comment: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/242